# visual studio 2015 could not find any controls on the page in code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I just inherited a project from a former colleague which was written in Visual Studio 2015 Community.
I am using 2015 Professional.
After I open his project, I see lots of errors reporting:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC30451 'GridView_COMPANYINFO' is not declared. It may be
>   inaccessible due to its protection
>   level.    CorporateActions    C:\TTDAS\HJ\Projects\CorporateActions_Product\RecoveryTool_20160330\Demo_HoldingsList.aspx.vb   187 Active

In code file, I also see this, no control is found in the dropdownlist:

[image]

His project is in UAT now so I know there shouldn't be code issue in it.

I kind of recall I had similar issue in VS2005 but in most cases the issue just disappeared without any change.

Can someone share me any idea on how to fix this?

This is really driving people nut.

Any clue is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did lots of googling and many accepted solutions actually scared me away by asking people to remove and reinstall VS, the issue was fixed quite simple:

For each page that has the error reported, add any control for example, a button, and then double click the button to go to code behind, by double clicking the button, VS will be able to find out the button in the code behind, more importantly, all the missing controls on the same page are automatically identified again. Once I did this on all the reported pages, the project is up and running again, all I need to do is to remove the extra buttons.

I hope this is helpful.